# QuickLook Preview Panel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, quicklook

I'm looking for some examples on how to use the QuickLook preview feature. I have an URL for a file on the hard drive and want to achieve the same functionality as pressing the 'Space' key in finder on a file or folder and get a preview windows on top of all windows. 
From what i've read in the quickLook API, QLPreviewRequest returns a preview of the file. 
Now the question raises, do i have to design my own window/panel for presenting the preview in or is there a way to do that automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QLPreviewRequest` stuff is for writing a QuickLook plug-in.  To present a QuickLook panel from an app, look at the `QLPreviewPanel` class.

Comment: thank you, will look over that and get back to you with my progress

Comment: Note: QLPreviewPannel is included in Quartz.Framework and not in QuickLook.Framework

Comment: Hi Vlad, I'm looking for a similar solution but am stuck on generating thumbnails when the panel is showing multiple items. Would you mind saying how you tackled that part?

Comment: I only did it for a single item. User was unable to select more than one for preview